Use Table Aliases in JOIN with USING clause?
I have the following query...
SELECT *
    FROM TDM_FORMS
    JOIN TDM_ATTRIBUTES USING (FORM_ID)

Now I want to add an OUTER APPLY to add yet another fetch...
SELECT COUNT(OP_CODE) OPCNT, LISTAGG(OP_CODE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OP_CODE) OPLST 
    FROM TDM_CONFIG {Where FORM_IDs are the same}

As the column is named FORM_ID in all tables, I need to specify in the OUTER APPLY that one of the Columns comes from outside the subquery. Usually I would just indicate the TDM_FORMS's FORM_ID its table & call it a day, like this:
SELECT * 
    FROM TDM_FORMS
    JOIN TDM_ATTRIBUTES USING (FORM_ID)
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(OP_CODE) OPCNT, LISTAGG(OP_CODE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OP_CODE) OPLST
        FROM TDM_CONFIG WHERE FORM_ID = TDM_FORMS.FORM_ID)

The problem is that USING cannot have qualifiers, so I'm getting ORA-25154 column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier.
Is there a way to do this without having to change the USING clause?

You can, at least in your maybe-simplified example, swap the order of the joins:
SELECT * 
    FROM TDM_FORMS
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(OP_CODE) OPCNT, LISTAGG(OP_CODE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OP_CODE) OPLST
        FROM TDM_CONFIG WHERE FORM_ID = TDM_FORMS.FORM_ID)
    JOIN TDM_ATTRIBUTES USING (FORM_ID)

Or you can add a subquery (inline view) with the USING, and join to that result:
SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM TDM_FORMS
        JOIN TDM_ATTRIBUTES USING (FORM_ID)
    ) TDM_FORMS -- or use another alias
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(OP_CODE) OPCNT, LISTAGG(OP_CODE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OP_CODE) OPLST
        FROM TDM_CONFIG WHERE FORM_ID = TDM_FORMS.FORM_ID)

which is longer but maybe more robust.
fiddle

You can use a subquery. For example, the invalid Oracle query:
select *
from t
join u using (a)
join v on v.d = t.a; -- 'a' is valid, but not 't.a'


ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier

Can run well as:
select *
from (
  select *
  from t
  join u using (a)
) x
join v on v.a = x.a; -- 'x.a' can be qualified in the outer scope

Result:
 A    B    C    A    D   
 ---- ---- ---- ---- --- 
 100  abc  ghi  100  mno 

See running example at db<>fiddle.
